# How do I add padding between an img and its box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

I have images in a web page with the following code:

```
<a href="../images/Stacking_StackProcess_marked.png" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Stacking_StackProcess_marked.png" alt="Per line stacking calculation" width=600 height=520></img></a>
```

The image is styled with the following CSS:

```
img {
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(132,133,137,0.4);
}
```

The image has lines right up against the edge, and as they blend into the shadow they become very difficult to see; unfortunately changing the images isn't an option, so I need to add some space between the image and the shadow.

I've tried adding some extra space to the sides with `style="padding: 1em;"` and the like, but without any visible difference. `margin` doesn't seem to affect it either.

Any thoughts? Ideally, I want to add about 1em of space to the left and right of the picture.

Comment: ...I found the problem. I'd been editing the page on our SharePoint and refreshing the page on my computer. No wonder it wasn't updating. Ah well, we all need an embarrassing coding fail occasionally. ;-)

Comment: Still, @Saurav's solution is cleaner than what I'd been doing anyway, so it all worked out in the end. :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `box-shadow` on the `<a>` tag instead of image and then give the `padding` to it, just like:

```
a {
  display: inline-flex; /* Or you can use 'inline-block' */
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(132,133,137,0.4);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen*):

```css
a {
  display: inline-flex; /* Or you can use 'inline-block' */
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(132,133,137,0.4);
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="../images/Stacking_StackProcess_marked.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Per line stacking calculation" width=600 height=520></img></a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works nicely, thanks, and polishes up the code a bit too!

Comment: @AndrewPerry Its my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Padding is working fine.

```
img {
  padding:20px;
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(132,133,137,0.4);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lpm44h0/

Comment: Thanks - so it does. Turned out I'd been editing one file and refreshing another and wondering why nothing seemed to change it... Thanks anyway!